# Setup of Joli.js in Appcelerator App

Tags: database, model, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to use the https://github.com/xavierlacot/joli.js Active Record style model for Titanium but a falling at the first hurdle...

My app.js file contains the init code suggested in the read me.

```
 var db = require('joli').connect('myDb');
   Ti.inc
```

I have had a look around and cannot find any examples that explain how to setup the database when using Joli.  Does the db.model.initialize(); method setup a new database if one does not exist and migrate tables for each model defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try

https://github.com/xavierlacot/joli.js-demo

This has the examples that you required.

Abishek R Srikaanth